# How to refer to header rather than column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to change this code so instead of referring to a column by RC number it refers to it by the name of the header.

The end result looks as simple as this:
PRESTIGE WORLDWIDE  INC. / 123 TacoTaco DR

The address is broken out into three columns which are RC-103 102 101 in the code.

```vb
Sub ProjectName()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro Time") ' change to name of your sheet

    Dim x As Long

    x = 2 '************CHANGE BACK TO 2********************
    
    Do Until ws.Cells(x, 7) = ""
    
        With ws.Cells(x, 120)   
            .Value = "=iferror(""""&RC[-86]&"" / ""&RC[-103]&"" ""&RC[-102]&"" ""&RC[-101]&"""",)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        
        x = x + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

I tried a few methods and failed with all of them.

I will need to do this to about 300 separate RC numbers and plan to do this probably close to 1,000 more times in multiple spreadsheets.

---

This was the answer.

```vb
Sub ProjectName()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro Time") ' change to name of your sheet

    Dim projectCell As Range ' Project Name
    Dim amlCell As Range ' AML_PROV_PATH
    Dim ultCustNameCell As Range ' ULTIMATE_CUST_NAME
    Dim sanoCell As Range ' SANO
    Dim sasnCell As Range ' SASN
    Dim sathCell As Range ' SATH
    
    Set projectCell = FINDCOLUMN("Project Name")
    Set amlCell = FINDCOLUMN("AML_PROV_PATH")
    Set ultCustNameCell = FINDCOLUMN("ULTIMATE_CUST_NAME")
    Set sanoCell = FINDCOLUMN("SANO")
    Set sasnCell = FINDCOLUMN("SASN")
    Set sathCell = FINDCOLUMN("SATH")
    
    Dim x As Long
    x = 2 '************CHANGE BACK TO 2********************
    
    Do Until ws.Cells(x, amlCell.Column) = ""
    
        With ws.Cells(x, projectCell.Column)
            .Value = "=iferror(""" & ws.Cells(x, ultCustNameCell.Column).Text & " / " _
                               & ws.Cells(x, sanoCell.Column).Text & " " _
                               & ws.Cells(x, sasnCell.Column).Text & " " _
                               & ws.Cells(x, sathCell.Column).Text & """ ,)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: [This question is possibly relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39755639/4088852)

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use R1C1 notation is so that you can assign relative formula across a range of cells.  There is no need to loop over individual cells.  Simply define a range and the formula to the entire range.

Here are 4 ways to define the range and assign a formula to it.  Each method has a slightly different approach but all the methods return the same results.

If first three methods use `.End(xlDown)` and will not work properly if there is only 1 row of data.

Method 4 is probably the best.  It uses `.End(xlUp)` and will fail if you have multiple lists in column 7.

The 2nd, 3rd and 4th methods first define a range that extends from `Cell(2, 7) to the last used cell and then extends the range to include all the cells in those rows using`EntireRow`.  In this way you will not need to calculate the offset of the columns.  Next`Columns(120)` is used to target all the cells in column 120 of the range.

---

**Note:** I think this is what you are wanting to use.

Methods 3 & 4 uses a different variation of the R1C1 notation.  Instead of using the offset of column 120 it uses the actual column number of the current row.  For example:  Instead of using the offset of column 120 `RC[-86]` to refer to column  34 (120-86) it uses `RC34`.

---

```
With Sheets("Macro Time")
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(2, 7).End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 113)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(""""&RC[-86]&"" / ""&RC[-103]&"" ""&RC[-102]&"" ""&RC[-101]&"""",)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

With Sheets("Macro Time")
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(2, 7).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Columns(120)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(""""&RC[-86]&"" / ""&RC[-103]&"" ""&RC[-102]&"" ""&RC[-101]&"""",)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

With Sheets("Macro Time")
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(2, 7).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Columns(120)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(""""&RC34 &"" / ""&RC17&"" ""&RC18&"" ""&RC19&"""",)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

With Sheets("Macro Time")
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Columns(120)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(""""&RC34 &"" / ""&RC17&"" ""&RC18&"" ""&RC19&"""",)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```